# Avoiding StackOverflowError with adding and subtracting 32 digit numbers

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I seem to be unable to stumbling into some recursion problems with my latest code. I am adding and subtracting custom numbers of 32 digits. The numbers are stored in an array.

Here's the bit of code to illustrate my problems:

```
    public Custom subtract(Custom e) {
     if (isPositive(this) && (!isPositive(e))) {
         return add(temp);
    }
```

In the add method:

```
      if (isPositive(this)) {
            if (!isPositive(e)) {
                if (this.e.array.length >= e2.array.length) {
                    return subtract(e);
```

The problem is, the length will always be constant and the sign will always be a constant too for the passed in parameters. I think my best bet would be to make copies of each Custom Object and changing the signs to satisfy an add or subtract but in doing so, I overwrite existing, correct values. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: You simply have an infinite loop there: your add will always call `subtract`, and subtract will always call `add`. You should stop it somewhere, for example, by introducing a `negate()` method, especially given that your snipped actually doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. Look at JDK implementation of BigDecimal for example.

Comment: You have not shown the entire "custom number" class (`Custom`) in which these methods live. Without seeing the entire class we cannot help you.

Comment: I am having trouble with differentiating numbers, basically. So, like arrayOne will be [7], length 1. arrayTwo will be [-6], length 1. When I add arrayOne and arrayTwo, I will be calling the subtraction method. However, if I were to do arrayTwo - arrayOne. I would be calling the add method, in actuality. There gives my infinite recursion.

Comment: If you make a deep copy, you shouldn't have the problem with overwriting correct values.

Comment: What do you mean by a deep copy?

Comment: It means you copy what's in the object instead of the object itself.  If you have an array, you don't copy the array - you copy the individual values in the array.  If you have an object, you don't copy the object - you copy everything IN the object.  And if something in there is also an object, you copy everything in there too.  (It's OK to copy Strings even though they're an object, though, because Strings are immutable.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public Custom subtract(Custom e) {
 if (isPositive(this) && (!isPositive(e))) {
     Custom temp = new Custom(negate(e));
     return add(temp);
}
```

Where `negate()` returns its parameter with the sign flipped.

Comment: Just for reference, say I have 6 - -4, that is 10. And if I were doing -6 - 4 = -10. However, when I call the subtract method, -4 - 6, it seems to be subtracting the values at face value, say -4 - 6, so it will be -2, rather than 10.